# How to pass User Defined Table Type as Stored Procedured parameter in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008, we can define a table type and use it as a stored procedures' parameter.

But how can I use it in C# invocation of this stored procedure? In other words, how to create a table or list and pass it into a stored procedure in C# code with this new feature of SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to see this [example on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sqlserver2008.aspx).

```
SqlParameter param = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileDetails", dt);
```

where dt is a DataTable, 
and the @fileDetails parameter is a table type in SQL:

```
create type FileDetailsType as table
(
    FileName        varchar(50),
    CreatedDate        varchar(50),
    Size       decimal(18,0)
)
```

**Edit**:
[This MSDN Developer's Guide article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) also would help.

Comment: Is this option more efficient to insert multiple records?

compared to calling an SP within a foreach and iterating many times?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is by passing a `DataTable` as the parameter. Check out some examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I need to specify the data type explicitly

```
SqlParameter param = sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@something", dtSomething); // dtSomething is a DataTable
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
param.TypeName = "dbo.type_something"; // The name of the User-Defined Table Type
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx), linked to in [Jeff Meatball Yang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1030859/173497):

> System.Data.SqlClient supports populating table-valued parameters from DataTable, DbDataReader or System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable ([T:System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1)] objects. You must specify a type name for the table-valued parameter by using the TypeName property of a SqlParameter. The TypeName must match the name of a compatible type previously created on the server. The following code fragment demonstrates how to configure SqlParameter to insert data.