# Best Way to Insert Multiple Rows (ADO.NET)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I'm adding features to an existing ASP.NET project. The code calls a stored procedure to add a row to a particular table. I need the option of also allowing one of the columns to have multiple values, in which case a row would be added for each value in that column.

I know I can call my insert method once for each row, but that sounds horribly inefficient. I know I could write multiple lines, delimited by semi-colons, and send them to the database in one request. But the existing code calls a stored procedure and so multiple insert statements would require I modify the heck of the existing code.

Note that the multiple values will be stored as multiple lines in a textbox, one line per value, and must obviously checked for being correctly entered.

Is there a simpler way to approach this?

Comment: +1 - I am also interested in the answer to this question

Comment: What version of SQL Server please? The answer can differ from 2000 to 2005 to 2008...

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what they'll be using on the server. So I probably wouldn't want to target anything specific that came after 2005.

Comment: How about ADO.Net DataTable? I am not sure how the code is generated for that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 has the "table type" parameters that allows multiple rows as parameters. An example is defined in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030848/how-to-pass-user-defined-table-type-as-stored-procedured-parameter-in-c)

SQL Server 2005+ has good XML handling. We use this currently for small datasets. SQL Server 2000 XML handling isn't as nice.

For all versions, you can create a temp table then call a stored proc that uses this table. You can use SQLBulkCopy to load the table. Useful for many rows.

Generally, the problem is a common one. Erland Sommarskog has an article "[Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005 and Beyond](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)" which is (one of) the definitive articles on the subject (he has more).

Summary:

- table type (SQL Server 2008+)
- XML (easier with SQL Server 2005+)
- temp table (all versions)

Comment: Interesting. Might be a little more than I want to jump into right now.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstCol, SecondCol)
SELECT 'First' ,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Second' ,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Third' ,3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fourth' ,4
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fifth' ,5
```

Stolen from [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/08/sql-server-insert-multiple-records-using-one-insert-statement-use-of-union-all/).

If you are using SQL Server 2008 you can use this method:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstCol, SecondCol)
VALUES('First' ,1)
VALUES('Second' ,2)
VALUES('Third' ,3)
VALUES('Fourth' ,4)
```

Not sure how you could get this to work with a stored proc through...

Comment: Thanks but I don't see this being compatible with a stored procedure. The code above knows ahead how many values to insert, and would therefore need to be performed on the client end.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want with a stored proc, unless you do `EXEC sp_MyProc` over and over again.  You don't need to know the number of inserts that will be performed to use the above method if you use a loop to create the SQL statement that will be executed.  If you do use a loop to create the SQL statement be VERY careful that you are not leaving yourself open to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up sending a delimited string as one of the stored procedure arguments, and then parsing out each element from the string and adding a row for each one.

I'm not sure this is the best way to accomplish this, but it didn't require a lot of reworking existing code and seems like it should be fairly efficient to me.

Comment: This is actually described in my article link

Comment: At least one of those articles was extremely long. Could you be a little more specific about which link? Thanks.

Comment: "Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005 and Beyond". It is long because it is a complex subject

Answer (score 0):

Check out SqlBulkCopy, it will allow you to pass in your Datatable straight to the database.