# C# & SQL Server: move array directly into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Is it somehow possible to move a 2 dimensional array directly into a database (SQL Server) without transforming it into a SQL statement?

I know there was some kind of direct connection in vb6.0, but I can not remember how it was done then, nor if it is still possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass User Defined Table Type as Stored Procedured parameter in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030848/how-to-pass-user-defined-table-type-as-stored-procedured-parameter-in-c)

Comment: i will look into it. but it is not quite what i was thinking about.

Comment: Well, that's what you get when your question can be comprehended in more than one way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB6, you could avoid explicit `INSERT` statements by creating a recordset, inserting rows into it and calling `.Update`. This could be a "direct connection" if the `Command` mode was `adCmdTableDirect`.

In ADO.NET, you can also do so, but there are many ways, such as Linq To Sql or Entity Framework. If you want it plain low-level vanilla VB6-like style, that'd probably be [`DataAdapter.Update` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx).

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection c = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=..."))
{
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter a = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("select * from atable;", c))
    {
        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder b = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(a))
        {
            using (DataTable t = new DataTable("atable"))
            {
                a.FillSchema(t, SchemaType.Source);

                t.Rows.Add(1, "foo");
                t.Rows.Add(2, "bar");

                a.Update(t);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it did point me in the right direction. your code does help further.